# Create array of outer products in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have an array of n vectors of length m. For example, with *n = 3*, *m = 2*:

```
x = array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5,6]])
```

I want to take the outer product of each vector with itself, then concatenate them into an array of square matrices of shape *(n, m, m)*. So for the `x` above I would get

```
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  4]],

       [[ 9, 12],
        [12, 16]],

       [[25, 30],
        [30, 36]]])
```

I can do this with a `for` loop like so

```
np.concatenate([np.outer(v, v) for v in x]).reshape(3, 2, 2)
```

Is there a numpy expression that does this without the Python `for` loop?

Bonus question: since the outer products are symmetric, I don't need to *m x m* multiplication operations to calculate them. Can I get this symmetry optimization from numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe use `einsum`?

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5,6]])
>>> np.einsum('ij...,i...->ij...',x,x)
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  4]],

       [[ 9, 12],
        [12, 16]],

       [[25, 30],
        [30, 36]]])
```

Comment: normally I would put the `...` to the left: `np.einsum('...i,...j->...ij',x,x)`

Answer (score 0):

I used the following snippet when I was trying to do the same in Theano:

```
def multiouter(A,B):
'''Provided NxK (Theano) matrices A and B it returns a NxKxK tensor C with C[i,:,:]=A[i,:]*B[i,:].T'''
return A.dimshuffle(0,1,'x')*B.dimshuffle(0,'x',1)
```

Doing a straighforward conversion to Numpy yields

```
def multiouter(A,B):
'''Provided NxK (Numpy) arrays A and B it returns a NxKxK tensor C with C[i,:,:]=A[i,:]*B[i,:].T'''
return A[:,:,None]*B[:,None,:]
```

I think I got the inspiration for it from another StackOverflow posting, so I am not sure I can take all the credit.

Note: indexing with `None` is equivalent to indexing with `np.newaxis` and instantiates a new axis with dimension 1.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be solved using [numpy.broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
np.moveaxis((x[None,...]*x.T[...,None]),0,-1)
```