# numpy way of doing outer product of list

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to do a normalized sum of outer product of a 60000x100 matrix. I would like to do it using numpy way, since my solution is constrained by the python for loop in the list comprehension:

```
def covariance_over_time(X):
    B = np.sum(np.array([np.outer(x, x) for x in X]),axis=0)              
    B = np.true_divide(B, len(X))
    return B
```

Beware that, even this solution works, it's monothread, and therefore very slow when X has 60000 rows and 100 columns.

I have tried other approaches, like descripted here [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302358/create-array-of-outer-products-in-numpy).
The answer posted in the link, works for small matrices, gives me memory after a few seconds error. Do you know why? (Note: I have 6 TeraByte of RAM, so it's very unlikely that I have a memory problem, since I don't see the memory usage growing at all!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply use `matrix-multiplication` using [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

```
B = X.T.dot(X)
```

Then, normalize with `np.true_divide(B, len(X))`.

---

### Memory optimized solutions

If you still encounter memory error(s), we have two more options/methods.

**I. Full loopy solution**

We could loop through the second axis (columns) of `X` and perform matrix multiplication between each column against every column using two loops. Now, `X` has only `100` columns and thus, a full loopy solution would only iterate for `100X100 = 10000` times and at each iteration perform `60000` (no. of rows in `X`) sum-reductions.

```
n = X.shape[1]
out = np.empty((n,n),dtype=X.dtype)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        out[i,j] = X[:,i].dot(X[:,j])
```

**II. Hybrid solution**

A comprise between a full loopy solution and a fully vectorized one listed at the start, would be using one loop, which would perform matrix multiplication between each column against the entire array. This would do `60000X100=6000000` sum-reductions at each iteration.

```
n = X.shape[1]
out = np.empty((n,n),dtype=X.dtype)
for i in range(n):
    out[i] = X[:,i].dot(X)
```

Comment: Wow, very impressive. Thanks!